# How to access IWebHostEnvironment in class library .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core 5
I want to access `IWebHostEnvironment` in classlib but when I try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` in nuget I get this warning:
`A PackageReference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is not necessary when targeting .NET Core 3.0 or higher`
how do I do to access `IWebHostEnvironment` in .NET 5 classlib ?

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: See [Use the ASP.NET Core shared framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework).

Comment: To add to what @serpent5 said, you need a `FrameworkReference` not `PackageReference`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Double click the Classlibrary project to open the `<ClassLibraryName>.csproj` file, then, add the following code:

```
   <ItemGroup>
       <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
   </ItemGroup>
```

Then, you can use IWebHostEnvironment in the Classlibrary, the result as below:

[image]